# Typescript: Unsorted tuple

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to type an "unsorted" tuple in typescript?

```
type Test = UnsortedTuple<"Foo" | "Bar">;
const t1: Test = ["Foo", "Bar"]; // OK
const t2: Test = ["Bar", "Foo"]; // OK
const t3: Test = ["Bar"]; // Error: "Foo" is missing
const t3: Test = ["Foo", "Bar", "Bar"]; // Error: Extra "Bar"
const t5: Test = ["Baz", "Bar"]; // Error: "Baz" is not assignable to "Foo" | "Bar"
```

Edit: I used two elements for illustration. But looking for a solution that works with any amount of element types.

Comment: Not possible for any amount of elements.

Answer (score 0):

the error messages are not really helpful in some cases but they are there
for Tuples with mroe than 2 elements this approach would become quite problematic though

```
type UnsortedTuple<A, B> = [A, B] | [B, A];

type Test = UnsortedTuple<'Foo','Bar'>;
const t1: Test = ["Foo", "Bar"]; // OK
const t2: Test = ["Bar", "Foo"]; // OK
const t3: Test = ["Bar"]; // Error: Property '1' is missing in type '["Bar"]' but required in type '["Bar", "Foo"]'
const t3: Test = ["Foo", "Bar", "Bar"]; // Type '["Foo", "Bar", "Bar"]' is not assignable to type '["Foo", "Bar"]' Types of property 'length' are incompatible
const t5: Test = ["Baz", "Bar"]; // Error: Type '"Baz"' is not assignable to type '"Foo" | "Bar"'
```

Comment: by the way this also throws an exception in the case of 
`const t6: Test = ["Foo", "Foo"];`

Comment: Get it! I should have pointed out that "UnsortedTuple" should work for any amount of elements.

Comment: should ["Foo","Foo"] also fail ? and do you know the amount beforehand ?

cause if you Foo,Foo donestneed to fail and you know it you can 
` type UnsortedTuple<A> = [A, A,A,,...amount];

    type Test = UnsortedTuple<'Foo' | 'Bar'>;`

Comment: No  ["Foo","Foo"] should fail and I don't know the amount beforehand