# Typescript: only allow one occurrence of a value in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there an easy way to only allow one occurrence of a value in an array?

Lets say I have defined types like this:

```
  array: {
    value: boolean;
    label: string;
  }[];
```

I want to ensure that in that array, only one value can be true. If one value is true, the other values must be false. So for example I want to allow this:

```
const arr : array = [
    { value: false, label: '1' },
    { value: true, label: '2' },
    { value: false, label: '3' },
  ];
```

But I want typescript to fail and say that only one value can be true if I have an array like this:

```
const arr2 : array = [
    { value: true, label: '1' },
    { value: true, label: '2' },
    { value: false, label: '3' },
  ];
```

Is this possible in typescript?

Edit: To be sure, I only want to ensure this by types, not other logic

Comment: No, I don't think that's possible within the type system.

Comment: Not inherently, but you can build a class with a method which sets a `value: true` at an index. That method can first check for a violation of the rule and throw an error.

Comment: Does your array always have a fixed, small size?

Comment: The array is not fixed in size no, but it will probably never be above 10 elements

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, however not really useful in the real world to do this at the type level (at least in TypeScript). Your best bet is to just use the built in [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for simple values or a Set library which uses deep equality (such as [immutable-js](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js/)), which will allow you iterate through in insertion order and enforces that all items are unique.

---

For the sake of giving an answer which works using the typechecker though:

It's possible to use typed conditionals to return the type as `never`, thus ensuring the program doesn't compile. However, you'd need to know the values at compile time for this to be any use.

We can use a workaround for the fact TS does not have an equality operator using the technique descibed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53808212/7042389. We can then use that to build an array of unique types, where if one matches another its type is returned as `never` - this will force a compilation error as no value can be assigned to never.

```ts
type IfNotEq<A, B, T> =
    (<T>() => T extends A ? 1 : 2) extends
    (<T>() => T extends B ? 1 : 2) ? never : T;

type UniqueArray2<A, B> = IfNotEq<A, B, [A, B]>;
type UniqueArray3<A, B, C> = IfNotEq<A, B, IfNotEq<B, C, IfNotEq<A, C, [A, B, C]>>>;

const xs1: UniqueArray2<"a", "b"> = ["a", "b"]; // works
const xs2: UniqueArray2<"a", "a"> = ["a", "a"]; // string is not assignable to never

const ys1: UniqueArray3<"a", "b", "c"> = ["a", "b", "c"];
const ys2: UniqueArray3<"a", "a", "b"> = ["a", "b", "c"]; // string is not assignable to never
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=95#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgZgOQPbAKIEcA8BBANFAIXwBUA%20KAXgCgpaoAKTM%20gSkvOKggA9gIA7ACYBnKNigB%20KAEYoALigAmNjz5DhNOo2ZsKHLrwEjCkmfKVsp-CADcIAJ3PEA3FSqhIUAKr8AlugBXCGx7ewBDEEUcfAJyClhEFAxownwAbTxCAF1SVw9oH38gkPCQAGYUoigAYTiE5DQsTKr4BuSq6vxWpKb8TqgMmL6c0ly3AGMkfmFgKG5haQVCwODQiKiAIjCN-A2AIw26tK2dqH2NrOcoAHprqAB3JHsAaw1J6dn5xSW-FZL1zAnXbbI5As7bS43O4zey%20fgAcygvlE-BQUDCwmEvnh-DCewANtBgEgoNY7PYJlMZlAQAsfkVVqUKmDzrtxodKAMWQc2RdXO9qbTvt5fsU1uVAdtgadzqCpWceWd2ZDblAYXDEcjSWiMVicXjCVBiaTbA4gA)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to do this is through writing an exhaustive list of each possible scenario. You mention in your list that is will never be more than 10 - if you can make that a strict rule, then you can do something like this:

```
 type Array1 = {
  value: boolean;
  label: string;
}[];

type ArrayItem<T extends boolean> = {
  value: T,
  label: string;
}

type Array2 = [
  ArrayItem<true>,
  ArrayItem<false>,
  ArrayItem<false>,
] | [
  ArrayItem<false>,
  ArrayItem<true>,
  ArrayItem<false>,
] | [
  ArrayItem<false>,
  ArrayItem<false>,
  ArrayItem<true>,
];

const x: Array1 = [
  { value: true, label: '' },
  { value: true, label: '' },
  { value: true, label: '' }
]

const y: Array2 = [
  { value: false, label: '' },
  { value: false, label: '' },
  { value: true, label: '' }
];

// only z has a type error
const z: Array2 = [
  { value: true, label: '' },
  { value: false, label: '' },
  { value: true, label: '' }
]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=42&pc=2#code/AQFwngDgpsCCBO8CGYCMwC8wDeAoYwAbkgDYCuUAXMAEYD2dJUSAdgNz7AlI1QnUBnEPACWLAOYcAvgG0Auh1zhocRCgCSIKAFsAPABVgUAB5aWAEwG0GTVgD5MOTsXJVg+gDSduvfsCGiEtK4SpAwCMhgAEyOMpwRGlp6whR2XgQJYJo6ugBmpAJQafFqWUl5BUVecsAAPsBxGaXZevkkhcVNkS26KVUl3eVtHdV1DQOJOcP9XZOtlZ2qgzl9xQohAMZ0LELAxtSZ6FiNOESkFNR9Hlw8fNQA5PfAUumnLheg8BTXPnfAj89Xtgzq5Ll8oD9bn4AVJcHJNttdmADqUYsdOMD3m5ppDfA8ni8MSCPjibnj-gSgcS3FcyX8YXDFAB6JnAbYkMDAABewAAFkgrEhQGEjIg6PBcFsdiBuSjImjxgRMecaeDcfTKUSsdRSb9oZqldSwd86frnnCgA)

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean, but I do not think this would work for my use case, even though it probably newer will be all that big, I cannot enforce a maximum of 10 elements. Thanks for your input though! :D

Comment: @dtd ok - I don't think there is another solution (I tried a few) so it seems you may be out of luck. Fingers crossed someone can jump in to provide a better solution

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to only allow one occurrence of a value in an
> array?

It ***depends*** on your requirements.

This is the easiest/most readable way that I can think of, but it will allow only the first element of the array to be true, and all the others have to be false.

```
type normalObj = {
  value: false,
  label: string
}

type exceptionObj = {
  value: true,
  label: string
}

type normalObjWithOneException = [exceptionObj, ...normalObj[]];

const arr : normalObjWithOneException = [
    { value: true, label: '1' },
    { value: false, label: '2' },
    { value: false, label: '3' },
    { value: false, label: '4' },
    { value: false, label: '5' },
  ];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAdg9gJwLYEMA2B5ARgKygXigG8AoKKAN3QFcIAuKAM3QGcIAaMqNFLCNBi2AIAljADmJAL4kSoSFAgAPAMYQwwEXBjY8hUuSppaDYbU7kefAVCGiJ02fOjxk6XQHURwABYYYEACiquqa2gRQANrKahpaOrjsUAB0qa6omLiRALrZANyyKtpCUCgICFAM6e64Xr7+QSFx4YSRXORElDT0UGYc3Lz8DADkAIzDUFIW5MRdxj3MaGxJVkNQwwBME1Pts0YmTKz9qzbDAMzb0x1zB4vLA9YjACyXu537C0crg6cArK-kfIkIA)

This can be a limitation if your wish is to provide an order-agnostic type. But if we start with inverting tuples order, then the answer is **no**, an *"easy way"* of doing it
in TypeScript doesn't exist as of today (in JS we have plenty of options: sets, errors, proxies...).

If you care about an order-agnostic type, it is a topic that has been already discussed a lot (about inverting tuples):

1. [how to write an `Invert` type in typescript to invert the order of
   tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658536/how-to-write-an-invert-type-in-typescript-to-invert-the-order-of-tuples)
2. [Unordered tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61852773/unordered-tuple-type)
3. [Typescript: Unsorted tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505678/typescript-unsorted-tuple)