# Array that requires only one element to be a certain type

Tags: typescript

This just occured to me as I was playing around with API design in my head. In short, is there a way to define a type like this?

```
type SpecialArray<Unique, Bland> = [...Bland[], Unique, ...Bland[]];
```

But this of course gives me "A rest element cannot follow another rest element".

The closest I can get to is:

```
type SpecialArray<Unique, Bland> = [...Bland[], Unique] | [Unique, ...Bland[]];
```

which only allows the "unique" element to be first or last in the array. Note that this implies that the array must contain at least one element as well (the unique one).

Yes I have seen [Typescript: only allow one occurrence of a value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65794972/typescript-only-allow-one-occurrence-of-a-value-in-an-array), but the solutions do not work for any length, and I was unable to find any other resource on this problem. I am aware that I can write a helper function to enforce/infer the type for me, like this:

```
type Count<A extends readonly any[], T, Counter extends any[] = []> = A extends [infer H, ...infer R] ? [H] extends [T] ? Count<R, T, [...Counter, H]> : Count<R, T, Counter> : Counter;

type IsSpecial<A extends readonly any[], Unique, Bland> =
    Count<A, Unique>["length"] extends 1
        ? A[number] extends Unique | Bland
            ? A
            : never
        : never;

function helper<A extends readonly any[]>(array: IsSpecial<[...A], string, number>) { return array; }
```

What I'd like is a type that I can use like this instead:

```
const checked: SpecialArray<string, number> = [...];
```

Is it possible?
I will accept a solution to `SpecialArray<Unique, Bland>`, a workaround that is different from mine or betters mine in some way, or plain "no" and why it's not possible.

Partial (80% ) credit: implement `SpecialArray<Unique, Bland, MaxLength>`, that works up until the length given (some sort of permutation generator).

Please note that I want a **compile-time check** of some sort.

Comment: I don't believe a type can express this.

Comment: You can probably do something similar with a TypeGuard, but it implies the uniqueness check to be done at runtime, and the position of your unique type to be unknown.

Comment: The most robust way to do that would be to write a full class and manage that unique instance, but it'll be a runtime check instead of a compile time mostly.

Comment: Here's a validating helper that gives nice error messages: https://tsplay.dev/w23XVN

Comment: I don't see how you can do this unless you pick some arbitrary limitation, such as "the unique element must appear in the first 100 elements of the array", as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAQ4km).  I could write this up as an answer if you want, but I don't know if it's worth it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a permutation generator for small length tuples, as you have suggested, is quite straightforward if you're using the "counter" trick:

```
type SpecialArray<U, B, N extends number, R extends any[] = [U]> =
    R["length"] extends N
        ? R
        : R | SpecialArray<U, B, N, [...R, B]> | SpecialArray<U, B, N, [B, ...R]>
;

/**************************/

type Test = SpecialArray<string, number, 5>
const success1: Test = [42, 18, 'foo', 5];
const success2: Test = ['foo', 42]

const error1: Test = [42, 18, 5];               // No `Unique` element
const error2: Test = [42, 18, 'foo', 5, 'bar']; // More than one `Unique` element
const error3: Test = [42, 18, 'foo', 5, 3, 7];  // Too many elements
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAypDGBLAhgGwIICdPJAHgFUAaKAIRIDkoIAPYCAOwBMBnKBgVwFsAjCTEgCVqdRqyjIGIANoBdKAF4o0grIB8igFBQdUQdIBEqRgHNgACwPza9ZmwrbdTgPx7HTnQC49UAD6wEFAxsXEIScigKEmkAOjjBcPU-AIgkNCwcfGIySmiIuJjBdU0Abk1NAHoAKhrauvqG+ory0EgoABUIFmBFFLTgzLxuzEQGExJOXn4SAFY1TXgAewZuqBYOeHgulgBGb07VpWkAFgAmEh2ADhIAcgAzRcWb2dkypZWe9c3t0-2unqO90ezygZ1k5Xeq34mEWmD2HX+vRO5ygVxeJQ8mKcFQqkUWUAABgQGIgAI4cCAE6jGLiMYALZZQ7Cw34Iw7KM4Xa5QIFPWa3HjITA3V5QHFQACysOgFkkUGW0CJJPJlOpEFpDHpkJ60NhAGY-uzkVzbg8+VAZiQ9SQAOyisW49qPKBcSQgNUa4AsIA)

Answer (score 0):

```
type PrevIdx = [ never, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
    11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...0[] ];

export type PrevNum<D extends number> = PrevIdx[D];

type SpecialArray<T extends any[], Unique, D extends number = 10> =
  [ PrevNum<D> ] extends [ never ] ? never
    : T[D] extends Unique ? T
        : SpecialArray<T, Unique, PrevNum<D>>;
```

usage

```
type ThingWithThing = SpecialArray<["hello", "world"], "hello">;
> ["hello", "world"]
type ThingWithoutThing = SpecialArray<["hello", "other world"], "world">
> never
```

Comment: This only checks if the array contains an element, but nice try.