# An array that may contain any elements, but definitely contains some elements

Tags: typescript

I'm looking to describe an array type that, for example, allows any string, but requires some string(s), without ordering. As an example:

This "works" but enforces the ordering of required elements:

```js
type ArrayWithRequiredElements = ['foo', 'bar', ...string[]] | [...string[], 'foo', 'bar']
```

This doesn't work:

```js
type ArrayWithRequiredElements = [...string[], 'foo', 'bar' ...string[]]
```

Error: `TS1265: A rest element cannot follow another rest element`

A potential lead on this, but I couldn't figure out how to use it: https://catchts.com/rest-tuples#duble_rest

Is this possible, and can it be extended further to type an array that allows any elements but requires more than one specific element without regard to the order of any element?

Comment: Quite similar to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73887462/array-that-requires-only-one-element-to-be-a-certain-type), don't you think?

Comment: TL;DR: This is not possible in TypeScript, at least not without some sort of helper function. [Here](https://tsplay.dev/mqkJJw) you can see the workaround: using said helper function. However, in your case, it seems that using `as const` is required here as TS is not able to infer the type of the given tuple through the check. What's your use case for this? Maybe we can come up with an elegant solution with a better API for the enduser.

Comment: Thanks @caTS! Yes, looks quite similar. Using `as const` is okay in my use case. This is for an interface where the producer of an interface statically declares an array with certain features (as string names) it supports and the consumer can iterate this for feature detection.

The producer is required to include certain feature strings, the rest are optional, and I don't particularly care if they are unique (though it doesn't hurt if they are).

Comment: Sooo what does this look like? Do you have a playground of this?

Comment: Putting one together now based on yours!

Comment: I might have something workable based on what you have using instantiation expressions:

https://tsplay.dev/w2zbbw

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this one, but you can give it a shot

```js
type NecessaryStrings = 'foo' | 'bar';

type ArrayWithRequiredElements = string[] & NecessaryString[];
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't enforce the required elements:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDGEDOSCGAnEBlY6CWAdgOZQC8UA5AGYD2NFUAPpQEYYUDcAUF6JFAEF06VCADqeYAAsAShACOAVzzoIAEwCiAGwgBbCAWBIyUJLkJEA2gF0oAMlgJkaTDnzEb3LgHpvUAAJGALQQAB6Q8MAhwjToXPA0BGZQGCIgAFyCwqIS0nJKKuraegZGJjZAA