# Enforce TypeScript class decorator safety with constructor function type

Tags: angular, typescript

Given the following decorator:

```
export function MyDecorator(constructor: new(someService: SomeService, ...args) => ISomeInterface) {
```

when using it inside an Angular component I need the compiler to check that the client code does not forget to also inject the service:

```
interface ISomeInterface {
  someService: SomeService;
}

@MyDecorator
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent implements ISomeInterface {
  constructor(
    public someService: SomeService,
    private router: Router,
    private anotherService: AnotherService
    ...
```

this works well but it expects `SomeService` to come up first in the dependencies which is not very convenient if say I have another decorator with similar functionality. Any ideas how to enforce this constraint regardless of "position"?

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73887462/array-that-requires-only-one-element-to-be-a-certain-type) then? Unfortunately, since this is a decorator, I don't think any of the workarounds are possible.

Comment: @CaTS another way would be to force `MyComponent` implement `ISomeInterface` whenever it sees the MyDecorator annotation?

Comment: You can't "force" something to implement an interface. Interfaces are just contracts to make sure the implementation has a certain *interface* (usable type) to the enduser.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's really easy:

```
export function MyDecorator(constructor: new(...args: any & ISomeInterface) => ISomeInterface) {
```

Comment: Wait... what? I thought you wanted `SomeService`?

Comment: have a look at the interface definition, it does the job just fine for me